# Is it possible to serve a templated text file using spark? (java web framework)

Tags: file, templates, parameters, plaintext, spark-java

I am using [spark](http://sparkjava.com/documentation.html#views-templates) as the backend to a project I am working on. I noticed that spark has the ability to serve templated html, using a templating engine such as velocity, freemaker, etc.

However, this isn't quite what I want. Instead of serving an html template, I would like to serve a plaintext file, while still allowing me to insert parameters where needed. For  context, I am trying to allow the user to download  code examples based on the parameters they have supplied.

Does anything like this exist, or do I need to essentially build the desired file's content and return it as a string?

Example of what I am trying to do

```
// example.java

public class Example {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        System.out.println( {{ param }} );
    }
}
```

So this ^ would be the plain text template that I am attempting to serve... "param" would be passed to the backend via http request, and inserted into the file. Then I would serve the file to the frontend.

Comment: What's the difference between what you're trying to achieve to serving this content as HTML page (then you can use template manager) containing only this plaintext content only, except the extension which will be `.html` instead of `.java` if the user saves the file?

Comment: Giving this a shot.

Comment: This worked. If you wanna provide this as an answer, I'll give you the accept. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, (as mentioned in the comment :), glad it helped) you can serve this content as HTML page (then you can use template manager) containing only this plaintext content only. Only exception will be the extension which will be `.html` instead of `.java` if the user saves the file.

Answer (score 0):

You could declare a route whose return type is 'text/plain'

```
get(Main.API_PUBLIC + "/sourcecode", (req, res) -> {
    res.status(200);
    res.type("text/plain");
    return " /* This will be the code snippet you'll be returning */ ";
});
```

Another alternative would be putting your source code files into the static files directory and link to them in your html.

Comment: This was my initial idea. However, the source code files can get somewhat long, and formatting them correctly (eg: \t \n) seems like it will take a good bit of work. This is my plan B. Going to try and use the templating engine without any of the html tags.